# Error persists after removing the code

Tags: errors, equations, debugging, sharelatex

I accidentally added an erroneous backslash to a code in the equation environment. Even after removing it - in fact even after removing the whole line - the error persists.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.176 \rho^2 = \sum_{i,j} \p
                            _i \rho_i p_j \rho_j
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Double subscript.
l.176 \rho^2 = \sum_{i,j} \p_
                             i \rho_i p_j \rho_j
I treat `x_1_2' essentially like `x_1{}_2'.
```

My mistake was the backslash in front of 'p_i', which is indeed an undefined control sequence. <s>Apparently this also causes a mysterious instance of a double subscript.</s> Strangly, I still get this exact error if my document ends at line 171.

I tried deleting the .aux files and renaming the main.tex file as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12610/strange-persisting-error-even-after-removing-the-code), but that didn't fix it. I am using ShareLaTeX; is this a known problem?

EDIT: The PDF output also keeps the erroneous line after removing the offending code. Any edits to the previous code or new additions are not shown.

Comment: I edited your post to use `{}` rather than quote so line ends are preserved, as `\p` isn't at the end of the first line, did TeX break the line in the error message after `\p ? If so could you edit it back, similarly the doube subscript message looks malformed in the posting

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Ah okay! Tex did break the message: I've edited it back to the raw log.

Answer (score 8):

The double subscript error is not mysterious: If you had

```
\sum_{i,j} \p_i
```

where `\p` is not defined, then if you do not stop the run at the first error Tex simply ignores it and acts as if you had

```
\sum_{i,j} _i
```

which is two subscripts on `\sum`.

You should not take too much notice of any error messages after the first, they are often caused by the recovery operation, which is designed to get TeX unstuck and be able to carry on rather than do anything particularly sensible with the output at that point.