# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char -> from bibliography file

Tags: bibtex, errors, input-encodings

Recently I added a name in my bibliography file with the letter É. When I tried to compile, Texstudio gave me the following code:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:É. not set up for use with LaTeX N.~Nisan, T.~Roughgarden, É.

My first step was to change the letter to E in the bibliography file (Jabref) but the error did not go away. Even after deleting the complete entry from the bibliography I still get the same error.

My Latex document contains the following bibliography formatting:

```
\usepackage[comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' which was after square 

%Underneath should help with citing an article's title....
\def\mybibtexdatabase{Bibliography}

\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{title}
\bibinput{\mybibtexdatabase}
```

In what way can I get rid of the error message?

**edit:**

I found out that the file main.bbl (my main latex file is main.tex) still contained the bibliography entry that gave the error. When I deleted the entry from that file everything was able to compile again.

This solves my question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange persisting error, even after removing the code.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12610/strange-persisting-error-even-after-removing-the-code)

Comment: Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the problem; in particular the bibliographic entry that causes the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user-specific file issue that is resolved by creating the .bbl file again.

Comment: Compiling with `biblatex+biber` would allow any unicode character…